# doWork no respeta el tiempo del intervalo definido - android studio 3.6.2 SE PUEDE ARREGLAR?

Tags: android

He creado un Worker para hacer una tarea de prueba pero no respeta el tiempo del intervalo que es de 10segundos.

```
package org.miprofe.radioFun;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

public class WorkerMusic extends Worker {
    public WorkerMusic(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.i("mirar","doWork...");
        return Result.retry();
    }
}
```

Observar la frecuencia de los tiempos que debería ser de 10segundos, pero no lo es.

[image: Imagen de los tiempos transcurridos]

La declaración inicial en el Activity es:

```
mWorkManager=WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
pRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest
                .Builder(WorkerMusic.class, 10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
mWorkManager.enqueue(pRequest);
```

Comment: Hola Jesús, el mínimo valor debe ser de 15 minutos.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso el problema se debe a que si estas definiendo un [**PeriodicWorkRequest**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder), de acuerdo a lo que se define en la [**documentación oficial**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

> [**PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder): Crea un [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder) para
>   ejecutarse periódicamente una vez cada período de intervalo. Se
>   garantiza que [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder) se ejecutará exactamente una
>   vez durante este intervalo (sujeto a las optimizaciones de la batería
>   del sistema operativo, como el modo de reposo). **El intervalo de
>   repetición debe ser mayor o igual a lav ariable
>   PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS.** Puede ejecutarse
>   inmediatamente, al final del período, o en cualquier momento mientras
>   las otras condiciones se cumplan en ese momento.

Este es el valor de la variable PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` :

```
  public static final long MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 15 * 60 * 1000L; // 15 minutos.
```

**Para que se ejecute exactamente durante un intervalo definido, la duración mínima del intervalo de tiempo debe ser igual o mayor a 15 minutos**:

Si defines un tiempo menor a este se estará ejecutando en un periodo irregular.